# Howto run Pluggable Annotation API Processor from Maven?

Tags: java, maven, annotations, pluggable

How can I run javax.annotation.processing.Processor implementation(s) from Maven ? I really want to use **Java 6 Pluggable Annotation API**, not apt.

Comment: I've just found there exists also some maven-processor-plugin. Should it be prefferred to maven-compiler-plugin for some reason(s) ?

Answer (score 0):

It is an option (annotationProcessors) of the maven-compiler-plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html